# Use count instead of for_each for terraform resource

Tags: terraform

When deploying resources, the template terraform gave uses for_each. This poses as a problem as it will give

```
 Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on /home/baiyuc/workspaces/billow/src/GoAmzn-LambdaStackTools/configurations/terraform/sync.tf line 410, in resource "aws_route53_record" "subdomain_cert_validation":
│  410:   for_each    = {
│  411:     for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
│  412:       name   = dvo.resource_record_name
│  413:       record = dvo.resource_record_value
│  414:       type   = dvo.resource_record_type
│  415:     }
│  416:   }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options is a set of object, known only after apply

The "for_each" map includes keys derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.

When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to define the map keys statically in your configuration and place apply-time results only in the map values.

Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a second time to fully converge.
```

error when using `terraform import`.

I found a potential solution that suggests using `count` in this type of scenarios, but it didn't go into details. Anyone can give any details on how to do so?

The code of interest is for `resource "aws_route53_record" "subdomain_cert_validation"`:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "root_domain" {
  name         = "${var.root_domain}."
  private_zone = false
}


resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  depends_on        = [aws_route53_record.sub-zone]
  domain_name       = var.domain
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "core-domain" {
  name  = var.domain
  count = var.root_domain == var.domain ? 0 : 1 # If the two are the same, do not create this resource.
  tags  = {
    Environment = var.stack_tag
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "sub-zone" {
  depends_on  = [aws_route53_zone.core-domain]
  zone_id     = data.aws_route53_zone.root_domain.zone_id
  name        = var.domain
  type        = "NS"
  ttl         = "30"
  count       = var.root_domain == var.domain ? 0 : 1 # If the two are the same, do not create this resource.
  records     = var.root_domain == var.domain ? [] : [
    aws_route53_zone.core-domain[0].name_servers[0],
    aws_route53_zone.core-domain[0].name_servers[1],
    aws_route53_zone.core-domain[0].name_servers[2],
    aws_route53_zone.core-domain[0].name_servers[3],
  ]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "subdomain_cert_validation" {
  depends_on  = [aws_acm_certificate.cert]
  for_each    = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }
  allow_overwrite = true

  name    = each.value.name
  records = [each.value.record]
  type    = each.value.type
  ttl     = 600
  zone_id = var.root_domain == var.domain ? data.aws_route53_zone.root_domain.zone_id : aws_route53_zone.core-domain[0].zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "core" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.subdomain_cert_validation : record.fqdn]
}
```

Comment: What is the FULL error message, showing exactly where it occurs.

Comment: I added the whole error message.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is pretty common when using iteration and is caused by trying to use keys that will be dynamically generated at apply time. You need to make sure that your keys are statically defined so they're known at apply time, the value of the map can then be dynamic. Some good reference, for this issue and solutions are here

[for_each example and solution](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/for-each-value-depends-on-resource-attributes-that-cannot-be-determined-until-apply/6061)

[for_each example and solution](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/the-for-each-value-depends-on-resource-attributes-that-cannot-be-determined-until-apply/25016)